# /t/ sound is pronounced like [ts] in British English

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, pronunciation

My question is about the sound /t/ being pronounced more like [ts] in British accent. For example,
The words like Tomato, Peter, water, task, Tom, talented, take the /t/ sound is definitely not pronounced as /t/ (it can, but this variation is 100% in place) but with [ts] sound after the /t/ sound.
However, there are also several words that don’t actually follow the rule of it, like attach, toast, teach that these t sounds do not go for the rule of adding [ts] sound. The third category would be in the case of the words like task or tooth where either pronunciation is fine.
I wanted to ask Is there is rule for it? Thx!

Comment: There's no ts in any of those words in any mainstream British accent. It's possible you are hearing strong aspiration as an s sound, but that doesn't seem to fit your examples. I think you'd have to give us some audio samples (via soundcloud maybe).

Comment: As the t is released the tongue comes into more or less the same position it is in when making an s sound. If you have aspiration at the same time you will get a hint of s, but this is inherent in the t sound - it is not an extra sound. How much it happens may depend on where the tongue is going next (i.e. what the next sound is) but I am not seeing a pattern in your examples.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what your native language is.

Comment: @rchivers In most forms of English, /t/ is alveolar and does have slight affrication coincident with its aspiration. This is different from, say, German, where /t/ is alveolar and aspirated, but has little to no affrication. So while it’s true that there is no /ts/ (like in _bats_) in those words, their /t/ can be described as [tˢʰ]. This, of course, is equally true in words like _attach_ and _toast_, and I have no idea what is supposed to distinguish the two ‘groups’ mentioned in the question. But perceiving English /t/ as [ts] is not unwarranted.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There is a hint of s when the aspiration is strong, for sure. What accounts for the English /t/ having slight affrication when the German /t/ has little to no affrication then? Stronger aspiration? Faster release of the consonant? Faster release sounds more plausible to me but I can't say I know much German.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It can even go as far as complete assibilation. As an AmE speaker this has caused me confusion in England -- I remember being unable to make sense of a word (unfortunately I can't remember what word it was) until I realized the speaker was pronouncing /t/ as [s].

Comment: @rchivers I’d say the primary difference is that in English, the release involved the tongue moving slightly forward and remaining in a sibilant-forming position for a brief interval before moving into position for the vowel; while in German, it moves away from the alveolar ridge straight into vowel position. Essentially the same difference as regular [t] vs [ts] – the main (perhaps only?) difference is the length of time spent at the intermediate sibilatory position. Since /ts/ is so much more common in German, it makes sense that their /t/ would avoid assibilation.

Comment: @TKR Full assibilation is not a general feature of BrE, but it is a feature particularly associated with particular dialects, like certain Welsh dialects, Scouse (Liverpool), and particularly some Irish dialects (stereotypically Limerick, I believe), where non-initial /t/ can sometimes become something almost like [ʂ] (as famously chronicled by Frank McCourt in _Angela’s Ashes_ in the phrase ‘gesh oush of ish’, with the severely assibilated t’s Limerick kids were taught by their parents to suppress if they wanted to sound posh).

Comment: @rchivers Similar differences can be found in AmE as well, of course – just think of the difference between Janice from _Friends_ saying, “I told you so” and a character from _The Sopranos_ saying the same thing: the former is strongly affricated and sibilant, the latter completely non-sibilant (probably even dental rather than alveolar).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In my (limited) experience assibilation to [s] (not [ʂ]) is pretty common in middle-class London/Estuary English, especially in women's speech.

Comment: @TKR I’d agree there’s a higher rate of assibilation among women than men, but full assibilation – i.e., where _tell_ and _sell_  or _hit_ and _hiss_ become homophonous – is not common in my experience. Even in dialects characterised by heavy sibilant frication, /t/ and /s/ normally remain acoustically distinguishable. The only dialect I’m familiar with where complete loss of the alveolar closure is a prominent feature, is Irish English, where the result is the ‘split fricative’ I called ‘something like [ʂ]’ above ([s̠] would probably be more accurate).

Comment: Usually when fricativisation of /t/ occurs in BrE varieties it results in a non-sibilant not a sibilant alveolar fricative (i.e. [θ̠] - not the retracted diacritic - instead of [s] in IPA).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, that does make sense and clearly my original comment was too hasty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Affricated realization of /t/ is characteristic of (certain varieties of) London speech (Cockney). [Wells (1982: 31)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ty5RoXyTKQsC&pg=PA31) writes:

> A common allophone of /t/ in a London accent is a heavily affricated [ts], thus [tsɑɪʔ ~ tsɑɪts] *tight*, [ˈpʰɑːtsi] *party*. To an American ear, as mentioned above, this evokes the stereotype of effeminacy, if the speaker is a man; but in London it has absolutely no such connotations, being quite ordinary.

The affrication is indeed noted to be a characteristic of stereotypical speech of gay men ([Cameron & Kulick 2003: 90](https://books.google.com/books?id=RmKekTGLbZ0C&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90)).

Wells continues [(322–3)](https://books.google.com/books?id=a3-ElL71fikC&pg=PA322):

> [I]n broad Cockney at any rate – the degree of aspiration is typically greater than in RP, and may often also involve some degree of affrication.
>
> Affrication may be encountered in initial, intervocalic, and final position. In the latter it is usually preglottalized, as [aʔpɸ] *up*, [ɑːʔtˢ] *art*, [ˈna˗θɪŋʔkˣ] *nothing*. Non-finally affrication of /p/ is rare, but examples for /t/ and, to some extent, /k/ abound, e.g. [tˢəi] *tea*, [kˣoʊ] *call*, [ˈbetˢəi] *Betty* (the latter differing from [ˈbetsəi] *Betsy* in having a shorter fricative element). Sometimes the voiced plosives, too, are affricated – particularly /d/, as [dᶻɪʔkˣ] *Dick*, [bædᶻ] *bad*.

[Watson (2007)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/992DEF3999B0F2F20952870B188A77A5/S0025100307003180a.pdf/liverpool_english.pdf) also reports /t/ affrication "is common word-initially" in Liverpool English.

As for the "rule" you mention, however, I've never heard of anything like it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply! What I mean by 'the rule' i mentioned is basically about the selected manifestation of assibilation in /t/. For example,  the words with sound /t/  in intervocalic position, 'attach' and 'water', /t/ sound in attach is never assibilated but /t/ sound in water is always be assibilated instead. Is there a rule for it? I have been trying to find out why this is the case. Thank you very much again and really look forward to your reply.

Comment: I understand that, and I've never heard of anything like it. The examples you name are so all over the place in terms of phonetic environment, stress, and types of vowels, that I don't think one can derive a rule from them, suggesting the observation is defective in some way in the first place.

Comment: Thx for your reply!

Comment: I agree that it’s the observation that’s defective. I have never heard anyone make any audible distinction between the /t/’s in _attach_ and _task_. I don’t think the categories mentioned in the question exist.

Comment: I would contest the observation given by @Peteryu: as a native Londoner from the East End, in causal speech I hear the affricate in _attach_ (intervocalic with the stress on the syllable taking the t-) as well as _task_, _Tom_, _toma_-to (word-initial); a glottal stop would be used in _water_, _Peter_.

Comment: @Michaelyus Thank you very much for your reply!  I was literally gobsmacked at what you stated! Can I talk to you more about this since it is really important for me to generalize a rule of it. I mean it is not only because of the curiosity that I started wondering the rule of it. Is it fine to add u on any social media platform if I may？Thx a lot

Comment: @Peteryu You can also use the [chat].

Comment: @Michaelyus Hi Happy to talk to you here! We were talking about the assibilation of /t/ sound in the southern England accents. and I was simply wondering, does it apply to all /t/ sound? I mean besides the words that I mentioned, are the following words still pronounced with assibilation?  like the words, tan, teeth, teach, touch, and detergent? cos these sounds are the ones that I find are hardest to be pronounced with assibilalition when compared with others. Thank you very much and look forward to your reply!!!

Comment: @Nardog Thank you for your notification! and I made a mistake that I asked you the question in the linguistic chat (the same question I just asked Michael) cos I thought you were Michael who answered my question the most lately. Thank you very much for your reply to my problem, however, i read all the literature you mentioned in your reply and i found that the only related claim they make is that /t/ sound is only assibilated before a high and front vowel (/i:/) and can not be the case before such as low vowels (/a:/). But in fact, this is not true, the word guitar is an example. Thx anyway!